# Size wire for 125AMP sub panel 375 feet from main panel

Tags: electrical, wiring

Currently have 120/240 single phase service and would like to run power to my pole barn which is 375’ away. I am thinking that a 125A sub panel would meet my requirements. What size direct bury cable would I need?

Comment: You start with a load calculation to see how much power/amps you can spare from your main panel(plus sub panels).  A 125 or even a 200 amp panel is not a problem.  It is the size of the feed breaker, which might be anywhere from 40 on up to power the sub.  The feed breaker will determine the size of wire you need.

Comment: If I’m going to have a 125A sub panel, doesn’t it mean I will have to have a 125A feed breaker?

Comment: Not at all. Thing being, if you want a 125A feed breaker (where a 200A subpanel is probably a better choice for the hardware at the other end of the wire) you need enough capacity to spare 125A to feed it. The 200A panel could also be fed by a 90A breaker, or a 20A breaker. In which case it would be a 90A or 20A subpanel, with a 200A local disconnect. The feed can be any size equal to or smaller than the sub-panel rating, but if your 200A service has 150A of load calculation on it already, you can only spare 50A to feed the sub-panel unless you upgrade the service to a larger size.

Comment: In many cases a new service to the pole barn may make more economic sense, but that will depend on your local costs for the utility to connect it, as well as the cost of having two meters after the utility connects it, and you'd have to look into that .vs. a service upgrade to determine which makes economic sense for you.

Comment: What sort of loads are you looking to run at this pole barn?

Comment: You definitely need to figure out what loads you want to run in this barn, how long you plan to use it, and what your utility charges (both up-front and monthly) for a second service (if they will even provide one). What makes financial sense will vary greatly depending on whether you plan to use say 20A in the barn for some lights and a TV or 100A for a dairy farm operation, and also on whether you're planning to spend decades here or might be downsizing/relocating in a few years.

Comment: Barn will be a second home, one bedroom, small kitchen and usual home stuff. Most of the barn will be a wood shop, and auto hobby shop. Plan is long term.